# Inputmask Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mask

Eu preciso de uma máscara que me dê este resultado:

```
FB.B0.C6.E2.65.EB.D3.09.42.EB.23.C0.23.BE.D5.EF.D6.BB.A7.7C-6
```

Percebam que entre os pontos os caracteres são aleatórios, podem ser letras e números, mas que a cada 2 caracteres o terceiro tem que ser obrigatoriamente um `.`.

O penúltimo caractere tem que ser um traço (`-`), o último pode ser número ou letra. A máscara tem o tamanho máximo 61 caracteres.

Esse é o código que tenho, gostaria de saber o que está errado? Desde já agradeço.

```
$("#ReceiptCodeModal").inputmask('Regex', {
        regex: "([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\.){19}[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\-[A-Za-z0-9]"
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar `{19}`, você está dizendo que o que vem antes se repete **exatamente** 19 vezes. Mas pelo que entendi, este é o máximo de vezes que isso pode se repetir, então faltou colocar o tamanho mínimo.

Se deve ter pelo menos uma ocorrências de "duas letras/números seguido de ponto", você pode usar:

```
([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\\.){1,19}[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9]
```

No caso, `{1,19}` significa "no mínimo 1 e no máximo 19 vezes". Ajuste os valores conforme sua necessidade.

Repare que, como a regex fica dentro de uma string, o caractere `\` precisa ser escapado e escrito como `\\`. Além disso, o hífen fora de colchetes não precisa ser escapado com `\`.

---

Se quiser, pode também colocar os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que significam respectivamente o início e fim da string:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\\.){1,19}[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

Assim, você garante que a string possui exatamente o que está na regex (nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos).

Também é possível usar `{2}` para as duas ocorrências de letras/números:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}\\.){1,19}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}-[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

Comment: Top de mais!!! Obrigado pela resposta e pela explicação, deu certo aqui irmão. Valeu aí a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.{0,61}$)\w\w(\.\w\w)+-\w$
```

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^(?=.{0,61}$)\w\w(\.\w\w)+-\w$" autofocus value="FB.B0.C6.E2.65.EB.D3.09.42.EB.23.C0.23.BE.D5.EF.D6.BB.A7.7C-6">
```